# Why flash errors are not working all the times?

Tags: node.js, express, flash-message

I am using express-flash for flash messages. It worked perfectly until I used redirection to req.header("Referer"). In particular I am trying to add a product to a shopping cart, but I don't want it to be added in case it is already in the cart. The following code is troubling me, since I don't get its behavior.

```
router.get("/add/:id, (req, res) =>{
    var backURL= req.header("Referer") || "/";
    var cart= req.session.cart;
    var productId= req.params.id;
    var found=0;
    cart.items.forEach(item =>{
        if(item.id===productId){
            found=1;}
    })
    if(found){
        req.flash("error", "Item Already in Cart");
        res.redirect(backURL);} else{
        res.redirect(backURL); }
})
```

This middleware does other things like adding items to the cart in case they are not present. That part works well and by console.logging variable found, I am sure that the code always finds duplicates, but it returns flash errors not all the times. I am using ejs as view engine. Can anybody help? thanks a lot

PS of course I passing errors to ejs with

```
router.use( (req,res,next)=>{
    res.locals.error =  req.flash("error");
    next();)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the message in session and read it from the session in the target page to display the message, Because before the session gets save for the flash message, it does a redirect. Go through ref 1 for more details.

```
req.flash('message', 'Please check your email to confirm it.');
req.session.save(function () {
  res.redirect('/register');
});
```

Ref 1: https://github.com/mweibel/connect-session-sequelize/issues/20 
Ref 2 : https://github.com/mweibel/connect-session-sequelize/issues/7#issuecomment-59469816

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem is that also after saving the session it gives me the same problem. Sometimes errors are flashed and sometimes not for the same action